# POSTing to REST endpoint returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, rest

When trying to POST some data to a SP list, I get an error telling me:
 `An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.` Interestingly, the testSubmit function works just fine without the `Image_x0020_Location` line.

For example, this (full function) doesn't work and yields the aforementioned error.

```
this.testSubmit = function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: this.rootUrl + this.apiUrl + this.listUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Submitted_x0020_VideosListItem' },
            'Title': this.sub.title,
            'URL0': this.sub.url,
            'Image_x0020_Location': this.sub.imgurl,
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": this.sub.formDigest
        },
        success: function successCallback(data) {
            console.log("Test insert was a success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log("Test insert failed");
            console.log(data);
            }

    });
};
```

However, replacing `data` with

```
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Submitted_x0020_VideosListItem' },
            'Title': this.sub.title,
            'URL0': this.sub.url,
            //'Image_x0020_Location': this.sub.imgurl,
        }),
```

Works just fine, although it doesn't submit an image URL like it ought to.

Why is this, and how can I get it working?

---

Huh. Changing the TestSubmit method to include

```
data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Submitted_x0020_VideosListItem' }, 
            Title: "Test item",
            URL0: "https://google.com",
            'Image_x0020_Location': { Description: "Image location", Url: "https://testing.image" }
        }),
```

has worked like a charm. However, my more generalized method is showing some strange behaviour.

```
this.uploadItem = function (sub) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: this.rootUrl + this.apiUrl + this.listUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Submitted_x0020_VideosListItem' },

            Title: sub.title,
            URL0: sub.url,
            'Image_x0020_Location': {
                __metadata: { "type": "SP.FieldUrlValue" },
                Description: sub.title,
                Url: sub.imgurl
            },
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": sub.formDigest
        },
        success: function successCallback(data) {
            console.log("Item insert was a success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log("Item insert failed");
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Returns as success, but doesn't include the success data I'd expect. Instead of a JSON object, it gives me...
The HTML of the page that I'm on.

```
Item insert was a success
<html lang="en" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" ng-app="submissionForm">  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example</title>
<link href="./JavaScript/jcarousel.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="...
```

what

To top it off, it's not being properly added to the list.

---

In the end, the strange behavior was caused by the callback structure I was using. Tightly-coupling the code let everything work as intended.

Comment: Which type column of "Image_x0020_Location" ?

Comment: `Image_x0020_Location` is a "Hyperlink or Picture"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [post](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/990131/crud-operation-to-list-using-sharepoint-rest-api) from Atish Dipongkor,

The right way to do the post from this type of column is:

```
JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Submitted_x0020_VideosListItem' },
        'Title': this.sub.title,
        'URL0': this.sub.url,
        'Image_x0020_Location': {
             __metadata: { "type": "SP.FieldUrlValue" },
             Url: "http://test.com",
             Description: "Url Description"
        }
    }),
```

Made my own test, and it worked:

```
<d:Test m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue">
    <d:Description>Url Description</d:Description>
    <d:Url>http://test.com</d:Url>
</d:Test>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was able to get the testsubmit() working, but the generalized form is giving me more (and stranger) trouble.

Comment: Why did you change your 'URL0' column if it was working? There's no need to change if it is a FieldMultLineText. Change back to be equal as testSubmit function.

Comment: It's working in the TestSubmit() function, but not in the Submit() function. I tried both the standard `'URL0': this.sub.url` and the Multiline one, and wasn't having luck with either of them.

Comment: Update your post with your `submit()` function then.

Comment: Heh, sorry, head's a little off kilter. The submit calls UploadImage() and hands off the returned image URL to UploadItem() -- that's included in the question text.